# Bash script - how to apply condition only to file and not to folder?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I have this line of code in a bash script:

```bash
  for file in "$Path"/*;

  do
    unpack $file
  done
fi
```

`unpack` is the function that will run on the file.

Now I want it to run only on files - on folder.

How can this be done?

Comment: Replace `unpack $file` with `[[ -f $file ]] && unpack "$file"`.  The quotes are important.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to identify missing quotes, and many other problems, in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This works even if the filenames have whitespace or glob characters in them:

```sh
for file in "$Path"/*
do
  if test -f "$file"
  then
    unpack "$file"
  fi
done
```

If you really are just running one command on the files, you can use this shorthand:

```
test -f "$file" && unpack "$file"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `find` command to find files or folders with specific properties.  The `-type f` argument means it will only return files, not folders.

Try something like this for the first line of your script:

```sh
for file in $(find "$Path" -type f)
```

Also note that the `fi` at the end of your script is incorrect because there is no corresponding `if` statement.  And I'm not really sure what you mean by "files - on folder": maybe you had a typo.

Comment: hey, thanks - but where do I put the "$Path"/* ?

Comment: Sorry, I added that to my answer.  Paths always go at the beginning of the `find` command.  You can run `man find` for more info about that command.

Comment: `for` loops over command output (including `find` output) don't work in general.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  It describes how to use `find` reliably.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) also identifies the problem ([SC2044 - For loops over find output are fragile. ...](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044)).